# ag-grid Multi-Level Sorting for Groups

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid with row grouping across 2 different levels: Title and Date.

How do I get the group column to display the hierarchy such that Title (rowGroupIndex: 0) is sorted ascending but Date (rowGroupIndex: 1) is sorted descending?

I've already tried setting the sort attributes on their column definitions and comparator: agGrid.defaultGroupComparator, but it will only follow one side. Either the group column displays Titles and Dates both in ascending or both in descending.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparator can access each node object being sorted, determine which column it's from and return a response appropriate to whether you want that column sorted ascending or descending.